# Functions continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have a question regarding continuity of a function that has 2 parts and 2 variables:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\arctan x}{1 + x^2},  & \text{for $x\ge $ 0} \\
A e^x + B, & \text{for $x<$ 0}  \\
\end{cases}$$

In order for a function of 2 parts to be continuous, I have to see what happens at the limit as $x\to 0$, then I get
$0$ for $x\ge 0$ and
$A + B$ for $x < 0$.

The next step would be to say that the second equation, $A+B=0$

Now, I am stuck here, what is the next step to find $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: The title and the first sentence on your question display partial misunderstanding of what's going on. Your function $f$ is a function of one variable, it is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. The numbers $A$ and $B$ are fixed constants. For some $A$ and $B$ the function is continuous, for others it isn't. You found that it is continuous for any $A$ and $B$ such that $A+B=0$. That's it, there's nothing else to find. Equivalently you have $B=-A$, so $f$ is continuous if, and only if, $f(x)=Ae^x-A$ for any $A\in \mathbb R$ and any $x<0$.

Comment: @GitGud that is my fault.. I am coming from programming, so everything that is not a digit, is a variable..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that once you know that $A = -B$, then the specific value matters not, as we have
$$Ae^x - A = A(e^x - 1),$$
which is zero for $x=0$ for all $A \in \mathbb{R}$. So, the answer should be that the function is continuous whenever $A=-B$.

Comment: A = -B in my case

Comment: Of course, I edit.